# C# Index was outside the bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I have the 2d array below:

```
long[,] arr = new long[4, 4] {
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
    { 9, 10, 11, 12 },
    { 13, 14, 15, 16 }
};
```

I'm attempting to loop through each item in the array and finding items surrounding that point.

```
 for (var row = 0; row < arr.GetLength(0); row++)
 {
     for (var col = 0; col < arr.GetLength(1); col++)
     {
         var itemElement = arr[row, col];

         for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
         {
            for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                Item around = arr[row + i, col + j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once I attempt to look at [5,0] it's out of the index, how can I stay within my matrix?

Comment: Well depends on what your rules are. If they loop around (so the most right item counts as bordering the most left item in that row) you could use `%`, otherwise you would have to add checks to ensure that the looking around stays within the bounds of your array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
for (var row = 0; row < arr.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < arr.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            var itemElement = arr[row, col];
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    if((row + i) < arr.GetLength(0) && (col + j) < arr.GetLength(1))
                    {
                        Item around = arr[row + i, col + j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```